# better ways to do anagram group

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, anagram

Working on below problem of grouping anagram. My current solution is sorting each word by individual character, then map the same sorted value into a dictionary.

Wondering if any better ideas which has less algorithm time complexity? I am thinking about ways not doing sorting, like hashing, but hashing requires order character of words as well.

Post the problem and my code, written in Python 2.7.

**Problem**,

Give a list of words like [rats, star, arts, cie, ice], group same anagrams into buckets and output them.
[rats, star, arts]
[cie, ice]

**Source code**,

```
from collections import defaultdict
def group_anagram(anagrams):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for a in anagrams:
        result[''.join(sorted(list(a)))].append(a)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    anagrams = ['rats', 'star', 'arts', 'cie', 'ice']
    print group_anagram(anagrams)
```

Comment: If it's working code, wouldn't this question be better on Code Review?

Comment: @Tagc, code review is to review existing code, but my question is more about asking if better (less time complexity) solutions (it is not about my current code, I show my current code for the purpose of benchmark for better solutions).

Comment: `from itertools import groupby; {k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(anagrams, key = lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)))}` is a solution. Compare it with what you already have.

Comment: The solution you have seems fine. Small point: there is no point to use `list` in `''.join(sorted(list(a)))`. A string is already an iterable to which `sorted` can be directly applied.

Comment: I think that you meant `return result.values()` rather than just `return result`. The code is fairly quick. It takes about 1 second to run on the `yawl` word list which has 264,097 words. The code groups them into 235,485 buckets, implying that there are roughly 30,000 nontrivial anagrams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current method is probably best. To test things, I used your method, the method from the excellent answer of @bigballer and a third method which uses a tuple of counts as the key. To stress-test the methods, I used them on the massive (264,097 words) word list [yawl](https://github.com/elasticdog/yawl), running each function 100 times, and calculating the average time for each approach:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import timeit

def group_anagram1(anagrams):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for a in anagrams:
        result[''.join(sorted(a))].append(a)
    return result.values()

primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]

def group_anagram2(anagrams):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for a in anagrams:
        n = 1
        for c in a:
            n *= primes[ord(c) - ord('a')]
        result[n].append(a)
    return result.values()

def group_anagram3(anagrams):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for a in anagrams:
        counts = [0]*26
        for c in a:
            counts[ord(c) - ord('a')] += 1
        result[tuple(counts)].append(a)
    return result.values()



with open("yawl.txt") as f:
    words = f.readlines()
    words =[w.strip() for w in words]

print timeit.timeit("group_anagram1(words)", setup="from __main__ import group_anagram1,words",number = 100)/100.0
print timeit.timeit("group_anagram2(words)", setup="from __main__ import group_anagram2,words",number = 100)/100.0
print timeit.timeit("group_anagram3(words)", setup="from __main__ import group_anagram3,words",number = 100)/100.0
```

Output (on my machine YMMV):

```
0.486009083239
0.64333226691
0.797640375079
```

Really, all methods are pretty dang fast given the size of `yawl`, each taking less than a second to process over a quarter of a million words. Nevertheless, your original method is the clear winner. Furthermore, it isn't restricted to the Latin `'a'` to `'z'` alphabet. As to why it is best -- the key is directly constructed by Python built-ins (which run optimized C code) but the other methods use interpreted Python code. It is hard to beat built-ins.

**On Edit**: I re-implemented the second method using this list of primes, sorted so that more frequent letters (in the English language) are assigned smaller primes:

```
primes = [5,71,37,29,2,53,59,19,11,83,79,31,43,13,7,67,97,23,17,3,41,73,47,89,61,101]
```

It shaves a fraction of a second off the time, but not nearly enough to make it faster than the first method.

**On Further Edit**:

I reran the above code with the following tweak to the second method (as suggested by @bigballer ):

```
primes = [5,71,37,29,2,53,59,19,11,83,79,31,43,13,7,67,97,23,17,3,41,73,47,89,61,101]
primes = {c:p for c,p in zip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',primes)}

def group_anagram2(anagrams):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for a in anagrams:
        n = 1
        for c in a:
            n *= primes[c]
        result[n].append(a)
    return result.values()
```

With this version, the first two methods drop to a virtual tie, with the prime-based method slightly faster in my somewhat limited tests (faster by about 8%). Nevertheless, I still think that the first method is preferable since it doesn't depend on the fixed alphabet.

Comment: ord(c)-ord('a') will be slow. Instead you should set x = {'a':2, 'b': 3, c:'5'..} and use x[c], it will be much faster. i.e. n *= x[c]

Comment: for anagram3, you should not use [0]*26, you should use counts = 1<<26, and use bitshifts i.e. counts ^= x[c]

Comment: @bigballer You were correct about the dictionary approach to the second method, but I don't see how the proposed change to `anagram3` will avoid collisions (which would need to be handled).

Comment: you could modify the 3rd method. If any bit is repeated, then count += 1<<(26*2) and ^= (1<<26 + 1<<(1<<x[c])
That way, duplicate bits will be stored in the next 26 bits. Since repeats are rare, this operation wont have to occur often.

Comment: @bigballer That is an interesting idea. If I have some time later I'll experiment with it. A quick check revealed that 81.5% of the words in `yawl.txt` have at least on repeated letter, so I wouldn't call the situation of needing to record counts > 1 as being "rare".

Comment: Thanks for all the help John, mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 4):

**prime factorisation** is unique, and order of multiplication doesn't matter.

You could assign `a = 2, b = 3, c = 5, d = 7` etc.

then dab = 7 * 2 * 3 = 42 = 3 * 2 * 7 = bad, so your hash would be 42.

another option is an efficient implementation of `hash(frozenset(collections.Counter(word).items()))`

edit: probably the fastest would be to use 26 bits. For each character in the word, flip the bit corresponding to it. You may get some collisions, in which case you can dedupe on lookup

Comment: Nice idea, bigballer, is there any SDK in python which return a sequence of prime number?

Comment: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103

Comment: Prime number idea will not work (at least exactly) if the word has more than 6 letters. It will return collisions which can be deduped. Neat idea though!

Comment: @ElKamina why wouldn't it work for words with more than 6 letters? Do you have an example where it doesn't work? I'm confident it will always work

Comment: @bigballer Say we are assigning prime numbers sequentially. Then z=101. so zzzzzz would be roughly a trillion. With an unsigned int (4 bytes), you can store up to 4 billion. You could use a long, but that would help you until word sizes of about 12. In short, each letter requires 5 bits on average and more letters mean we need more storage size (for lossless).

Comment: >>> 101**6
1061520150601
>>> 2**64
18446744073709551616L

should fit into a 64 bit integer easily. If one's concerned, could always assign smaller primes to more common letters. And use adaptable integer size (i.e. have a hash table for each integer size, and based on hash size, choose hash table)